# Where is Spatial query in QGIS3?

Tags: spatial-query, qgis-3

I just installed QGIS 3.0 EA.

I wonder where the Spatial query is?

There is a ”count points in polygon” in the toolbox but it can’t count point within a polygon.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

In Processing toolbox> Vector Selection > Select by location.
There is the Spatial query.

Comment: My qgis 3 does not have a processing toolbox tho

Comment: @Luffydude Processing toolbox is a core plugin - make sure it's enabled from the plugin manager window.

Comment: @csk it doesn't allow me to enable or disable from the plugin manager.

Answer (score 7):

The **Count points in polygon** tool should work for you, though I'd be interested to see what output you're getting.

Input `polygon` and `points` layers in the **count points...** tool:

[image: count points tool]

Output from above:

[image: countoutput]

If you'd rather perform this via a **spatial join**, which I think is what you're referring to, note that QGIS 3.0 now offers a separate **Join attributes by location (summary)** tool in addition to **Join attributes by location**. Both are found under **Vector general** in the processing toolbox.

By running a spatial join summary, then clicking the `...` by **Summaries to calculate** parameter, you can specify `count`:

[image: spatial join summary dialog]

Output from above:

[image: spatial join output]

Answer (score 5):

In QGIS 3.0, the spatial queries operation can be performed with a tool called Select by Location. The tool can be found under the Vector Selection tool in the Processing Toolbox. See [spatial query tutorial](http://www.geodose.com/2018/03/spatial-query-in-qgis-3.html) how to use Select by location with some examples